# Como dar echo em um file em php?

Tags: php, html

Eu estou querendo criar um servidor de E-mail marketing simples. Então para isto eu tenho que pegar o conteúdo de um HTML e salvar uma variável em PHP.
Este é o meu formulário.

```
<form method="post" action="email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1> Enviar E-mails </h1>
    <table>
        <tr><td> E-mail: </td><td> <input type="text" name="assunto"></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Assunto: </td><td> <input type="text" name="a"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Arquivo HTML </td><td> <input type="file" name="arquivo" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="ok"> </td><td> </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Também fiz um arquivo php para pegar esta informação. Porém ele retorna um erro: **Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\emailmkt\email.php on line 3**

```
<?php
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
echo $arquivo;
?>
```

Como eu converto para string este valor? Como eu faço colocar este arquivo html em um variável?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `file_get_contents()`, que irá lhe retornar o conteúdo do arquivo em forma de string.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("AquiOLocalDoArquivo");

//no seu caso ficaria assim:
//Como o @gmsantos escreveu na resposta dele

$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
echo $data.

?>
```

Para você entender sobre o `$_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']` de uma olhada na documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) sobre upload de arquivos.

Mais sobre a função na documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: O arquivo vem a partir de um input

Comment: Sim, só mostrei como usar a função.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$conteudo = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
```

**Explicação:**

Ao dar um `var_dump()` da variável `$_FILES['arquivo']` podemos notar um array com alguns atributos do arquivo:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "arquivo.txt"
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(48) "C:\Windows\temp\php9775.tmp"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(102)
}
```

Na posição `tmp_name` temos o local do arquivo no disco. Por padrão o PHP grava os arquivos enviados na pasta temporária do sistema.

Com esse caminho, podemos utilizar o [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para então ler o conteúdo do arquivo e armazenar em uma variável ou imprimir algo na tela.